# php mysqli cookies login

Tags: php, session, cookies, mysqli

I dont know what to do anymore, when i login it's cool and then when i return back it logs me out but cookies arent destroyed, i want on whatever page i go to stay logged on, and yep, SUBMIT buttons i can press it because when i log in its not hidden, please help, im on the edge of losing it, improve my code if its wrong, and i know it is

```
<?php 

error_reporting(0);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","samp");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to the database: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}

session_start();


if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{

    $userName = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["username"] : null;
    $userPass = isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["password"] : null;

    $hashedPass = hash('whirlpool', $userPass);
    $query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'";

    $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row)
    {
        $session = md5($userName.$hashedPass);
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE Igraci SET session = '$session' WHERE Ime = '$userName' AND Lozinka = '$hashedPass'");
        setcookie("login", $userName,time()+3600);
        echo "You are now logged in with hash: ".htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["login"]). ' <a href="index.php?logout=1">logout</a>?';
        header('index.php');

    }
    else
    {
        die('Account has not been found.');
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['logout']))
{
    setcookie("login", "", time()-60);  
    exit(); # stop executing here
    header('index.php');
}

if(isset($_COOKIE["login"]) && mb_strlen(isset($_COOKIE["login"]) == '32'))
{
    $session = $con->real_escape_string($_COOKIE["login"]);
    $query = "SELECT Ime FROM Igraci WHERE session = '$session' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query( $con, $query); $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if($row['Ime']) 
    { 
        echo "User is already logged in with username ".$row['Ime']. " and hash: ".htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["login"]). ' <a href="index.php?logout=1"> logout</a>?';
        exit(); 
    }

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Roleplay Factory User Control Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome, please login to your account.</h1>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" placeholder = "Username" name="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder = "Password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
</form> 

<div class="footer">
<p>roleplay factory &copy; 2016 all rights reserved</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code line

```
header('index.php');
```

to be

```
header('location:index.php');
```